# How to use LLVMBuildStore API

Tags: c, api, llvm

```
long i=3;
long *j;
j=&i;
```

I want to use LLVM C API to transform above code especially last line into llvm code .Now I search correct function in the LLVM C API ,I think should use "LLVMBuildStore",but there is "&" operator,How can I translate it? LLVMBuildStore' second parameter is LLVMValueRef type value which refer to "i" in this case,how to get the address from this value?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have provided the address assignment expression to j, I suppose that the variables are not globals, but rather allocated inside a function.

So, to translate this C snippet into LLVM IR, you first need to allocate space in the stack for variable i and pointer j, and then store constant 3 to the address of i and the address of i to the address of pointer j.

In LLVM IR:

```
%i = alloca i64, align 8  ;allocation for i. %i is a pointer i64* to variable i
%j = alloca i64*, align 8  ;respectively, the type of %j is i64** (pointer to i64*)
store i64 3, i64* %i, align 8  ; i=3
store i64* %i, i64** %j, align 8  ; store %i (the address of var i) to the address of pointer j
```

I do not know how to generate these instructions using the LLVM C API, because I have never used it. However, hopefully there might be a relevance between the C and C++ API and maybe providing the code that I would write using the C++ API might help you get an idea of the type of arguments you need to use. I hope it helps.

```
AllocaInst *alloc_i = new AllocaInst(Type::getInt64Ty(M.getContext()), //Type i64
                                          0,        //AddressSpace
                                          nullptr,  //Arraysize
                                          8,        //Alignment
                                          "i",      //name of result in IR. Leave "" for default
                                          I);       //Add alloca instruction before Instruction I

AllocaInst *alloc_j = new AllocaInst(Type::getInt64PtrTy(M.getContext()), //Type i64*
                                          0,        //AddressSpace
                                          nullptr,  //Arraysize
                                          8,        //Alignment
                                          "i",      //name of result in IR. Leave "" for default
                                          I);       //Add alloca instruction before Instruction I

StoreInst *store_i = new StoreInst(ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt64Ty(M.getContext()), 3), //get constant 3 of type i64
                                          alloc_i,   //store to the result Value* of alloc_i
                                          false, 
                                          8,         //Alignment
                                          I);        //Insert before instr I

StoreInst *store_j = new StoreInst(alloc_i,   //i64* pointer to i
                                          alloc_j,   //store to the address of pointer j
                                          false, 
                                          8,         //Alignment
                                          I);        //Insert before instr I
```

Finally, consider using the C++ API instead.

Comment: thanks your example.now i knew the allocated value is already the point value，so do nothing for "&" operator,only when get the content ,need to "load" the content from the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the following C function

```
int main() {
      long i=3;
      long *j;
      j=&i;
      return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.8 will generate:

```
define i32 @main() {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i64, align 8
  %3 = alloca i64*, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i64 3, i64* %2, align 8
  store i64* %2, i64** %3, align 8
  ret i32 0
}
```

What we can see from the generated code is that clang generates a single basic block. 
In this basic block we generate three alloca instructions and three store instructions and one ret instruction which terminates the basic block.

For store instructions, you can use LLVMBuildStore(). 
LLVMBuildStore takes three arguments, the first being your builder. The second parameter is what you would like to store the third is where to store it.
For the first two store instructions, you can use just use the LLVM value that represents your integers.

For the third parameter use the LLVMBuildStore instruction directly without loading the variable. Where the second parameter is the LLVMValueRef you received from your previous LLVMBuildAlloca() which you got when creating :

```
%2 = alloca i64*, align 8
```